# Is there a way to backup all excel files from a disk?

Tags: file, backup

I need to backup all excel files from an old hard drive, unfortunately, they are all over the place. Is there a way (or a program) that will scan the whole disk for specific files (excel files) and save them locally on my computer?

I tried finding them manually, but as I said, they are all over the place. Some folders require administrator access, but there is no password set. The original drive has windows 7 on it, and it wont boot on the original device, however, I can easily browse through the files with no problem (other than that its really slow) when I connect the disk to my desktop.